# Xelatex and hyperref to file

Tags: xetex, hyperref

I would like to add link to video in the same folder where pdf document is stored. There is code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{run:film.mp4}{Movie}

\end{document}
```

When I compile it with PDFLatex, then everything is okey, I click the link in PDF document and video player starts to play the movie. But when I compile it with Xelatex, then when I click this link in PDF document, there is written that:

```
path/file:film.mp4 No such file.
```

The problem is that word "file:" is inserted before file name. How to solve this problem?

Comment: An equivalent document works for me with both XeLaTeX and pdfLaTeX. (TeXLive 2010 on a Mac). Is your TeX distribution up to date?

Comment: This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9997.4 (TeX Live 2010) -- I guess so.

Comment: all right I solved the problem, I used url package and it works for me.

Comment: So your example code wasn't actually sufficient to show the problem, which was caused by the specific URL that you were trying to link to.

Comment: Url is all right. With \url command it works, with \href it doesn't. When I write \url{film.mp4}, then the link opens video player and displays film, but not with \href{run:film.mp4}{Movie} nor \href{film.mp4}{Movie}

Comment: Maybe your `hyperref` is old? Mine is 6.82g

Comment: Yes, you are right. My version was 6.81, after upgrade to 6.82 it works. Thanks.

Comment: I've added my comment as a complete answer for the record. If you accept it, we can get this question off of the "unanswered" questions list.

Comment: @Jasper, yes, you're right, but since the problem has been resolved, it seemed reasonable to propose acceptance, too, since questions with accepted answers are are still better for the site than questions with just upvoted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your sample document worked fine for me with an updated TeXLive, it is likely that your TeX distribution is not completely up-to-date.

By putting `\listfiles` in the preamble, you can generate a complete list of all of the packages loaded. In this case, the relevant package is clearly `hyperref`. The version current at the time of this answer is `6.82g`. Check the version that you have, and if it is an earlier version, you should update it.