# XeLaTeX and href to a movie file with an image placeholder

Tags: xetex, hyperref

After trying unsuccessfully to integrate a video in my beamer presentation (but that’s because there is no or badly working support from open-source PDF viewer mostly), I’ve decided to switch to hyperref’s href command as follow:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \href{run:film.mp4}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{placeholder.jpg}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But, the resulting frame seems to have no clickable object. I’ve also tried in an article document, and it resulted in a tiny cyan square (that is hyperref boxing of links) in the bottom left of the placeholder picture.

If I use pdflatex instead or a text in place of the placeholder picture, it works. Any idea?

P.S.: I’ve seen [Xelatex and hyperref to file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20948/xelatex-and-hyperref-to-file), but it’s not the same issue and I’m using TeX Live 2017, so…

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Works for me with both xelatex and pdflatex (also using texlive 2017). Can you share the non-working pdf you created with xelatex? Off-topic: you don't need `\usepackage{hyperref}` with beamer

Comment: Does it work with `{example-image}` instead of your placeholder.jpg? If not: Is your texlive up-to-date? Your description reminds me of a bug that should have been resolved.

Comment: @samcarter I can share the PDF, uploaded at https://paste.xinu.at/eiD/. I can add pdflatex and article version too if needed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It works with {example-image}. In the article version, the image is squared with the cyan link boxing of hyperref instead of the tiny square in the bottom left in my case. So that would be an issue with my image? Regarding my TeX Live version, I’m up-to-date as of what ArchLinux proposes: https://www.archlinux.org/packages/?q=texlive.

Comment: Looking at the related section, I’ve seen this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84921/href-not-working-with-image-but-ok-with-text. Should I be using \XeTeXLinkBox?

Comment: Yes you should use \XeTeXLinkbox. A jpg doesn't create a sensible link box.

Comment: OK, I’ll do that and revive the XeTeX related issue so that this get fixed.